# How to get rid of the error message : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined" when I build Angular 9 in prod?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have created a .net core 3.1 / Angular 9 application using the Angular template in VisualStudio 2019.

I cannot deploy the application in release mode. I have pinpointed the problem to the Angular 9 build.

I can build my application in angular 9 using the command 'ng build', but when I try to build for production using the command 'ng build --prod', I get the error message
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined"

I don't use the trim function in my application

It seems to be coming from asset optimization optimize-css-webpack-plugin
[image: asset optimization optimize-css-webpack-plugin]

Here is what the log file looks like

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\styles.ff78110e0c95cd51fe03.css:7596:5
    at Object.attribute (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\dist\index.js:46:47)
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\dist\index.js:208:39
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:176:26
    at Selector.each (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:159:22)
    at Selector.walk (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:175:21)
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:179:31
    at Root.each (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:159:22)
    at Root.walk (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:175:21)
    at Processor.func (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\dist\index.js:201:27)
    at Processor._runSync (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:84:30)
    at Processor.processSync (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:177:27)
    at getParsed (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\dist\index.js:34:59)
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss-minify-selectors\dist\index.js:196:39
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:239:18
    at C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:135:18
    at AtRule.each (C:\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName]\[MyAppName].Web\ClientApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:101:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, but looking a little in the documentation I found this command and it helped me a lot:

```
ng build --buildOptimizer=false
```

In this way I built the application to production.